# Android SQLite rawquery returns only first record

Tags: android, sqlite

My SQLite query returning only one record, However, the table has multiple rows

```
cursor=mydb.rawQuery("Select category from items;", null);
```

I have even tried `GROUP BY` but still wont work.

I am new to SQLite, would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Please state a few lines of the content of your table and the code <b>after</b> rawQuery used to inspect the content pointed by the cursor.

Answer (score 7):

First of all your string query must not be terminated so instead of passing it as:

```
"Select category from items;"
```

you should try passing it as:

```
"Select category from items"
```

as mentioned on [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Also, are you looping over the cursor? Here is an example of how to get data out of a cursor with a while loop:

```
ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>()
while (cursor.moveNext()) {
    results.add(cursor.getString(0)); // 0 is the first column 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help jackerran, I have removed ";" but still getting the same result. Only first record is returned when I am trying to run the query as: "Select category from items GROUP BY category". cursor.getcount() is returning only one row. If i run the same query in sqlite on my desktop it works fine.

Comment: I would remove the group by since you should not need it. Have you verified in your database that the records are there? And that you are connecting to the proper database? Also are there any differences in your versions of java/sqlite/android sdk/ and operating systems between your desktop and laptop environment?

Answer (score 4):

First, search:

```
Cursor cs = myDataBase.rawQuery("Your query", null);
if (cs.moveToFirst()) {
    String a = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex("your_column_name"));
    cs.close();
    return a;
}
cs.close();
return "";
```

Get the information from cursor:

```
if (cs.moveToFirst()) {
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>()
    do {
            results.add(cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex("your_column_name"))); 
    } while (cs.moveNext());
}
```

Without if, I took error in my project. But this worked for me. By the way, your query doesn't look good. If you give some information about your database, we can help much more.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to select all items from the table:

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Tablename ,
                null);

Answer (score 1):

this can help you

```
public ArrayList<mydata> getallContents() {

    ArrayList<mydata> lst = new ArrayList<mydata>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + GAMETABLE, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            lst.add(new mydata(c.getString(1),
                    c.getString(3),c.getString(4),c.getString(5),c.getString(6)));

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return lst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need raw query method. i think that the android way is better in this case:

```
    db.query(items, category, null, null, null, null, null);
```

than use the cursor how already is written in the other comment.